# Hi ! I'm creating a dashboard of ipl using vue js

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I wanted to get the data by clicking on the (blue- button like season 2008, 2009...) I have used a v-for loop but unfortunately, by clicking a button it only renders one time. (bottom 3 tabs).
clicking a button I need the corresponding value of the data into the bottom 3 tabs.

The data is s like The data is something like this 
Data :[{
"Index":0,
"Sesson_year":2008,
"Orange_cap": "russel",
"Purple_cap":"mark",
"Manofthematch":  "dhoni",}, and so on...[image]

The code is -

```
<md-button class="md-dense md-raised color" v-on:click="selecteddata(filter.push(x))"
                        v-for="x in capData"
                        :key="x">   
                        {{ x.Season_Year }}
 </md-button>


 <transition name="fadeInRight">
 <div class="text-md-center centerd" v-for="value in filter"
 :key="value">
 <md-card class="md-primary md-card-scope" md-with-hover>
        <md-ripple>
          <md-card-header>
            <div class="md-title">Man Of The Series</div>
          </md-card-header>
           <md-card-content>
            {{ value.Man_of_the_Series_Id }}
          </md-card-content>
        </md-ripple>
      </md-card>

        <md-card class="md-card-scope orange-cap" md-with-hover>
        <md-ripple>
          <md-card-header>
            <div class="md-title">Orange Cap</div>
          </md-card-header>
          <md-card-content>
             {{ value.Orange_Cap_Id }}
          </md-card-content>
        </md-ripple>
      </md-card>

        <md-card class=" md-card-scope purple-cap" md-with-hover>
        <md-ripple>
          <md-card-header>
            <div class="md-title">Purple Cap</div>
          </md-card-header>
          <md-card-content>
              {{ value.Purple_Cap_Id }}
          </md-card-content>
        </md-ripple>
      </md-card>
      </div>
 </transition>
       </md-card>
      </div>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
         return {
            capData: [],
            x: '',
            filter: [],
        }   
    }, 
    methods: {
      selecteddata () {
     }  
    },
    mounted () {
        this.$axios.get('https://mighty-garden-54587.herokuapp.com/getOrangePurpleSeries')
        .then(({ data }) => {
        this.capData = data.data         
        })      
    }    
}
</script>
```

Comment: A quick answer will be passing an identifier(year) to the method, then find that item in this.capData and update this.filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify code as below and it should work ( pls modify css accordingly)

```
  <template> 
  <div>
  <md-button class="md-dense md-raised color" v-on:click="selecteddata(x)"
                v-for="x in capData" :key="x.index">   {{ x.Season_Year }}
  </md-button>
  <h5> val {{val.Season_Year}}={{val}}</h5>
  <transition name="fadeInRight">
  <div class="text-md-center centerd">
  <md-card class="md-primary md-card-scope" md-with-hover>
    <md-ripple>
      <md-card-header> <div class="md-title">Man Of The Series</div> </md-card-
   header>
       <md-card-content>{{ val.Man_of_the_Series_Id }} </md-card-content>
    </md-ripple>
   </md-card>
   <md-card class="md-card-scope orange-cap" md-with-hover>
    <md-ripple>
      <md-card-header><div class="md-title">Orange Cap</div></md-card-header>
      <md-card-content>{{ val.Orange_Cap_Id }} </md-card-content>
    </md-ripple>
    </md-card>

    <md-card class=" md-card-scope purple-cap" md-with-hover>
    <md-ripple>
      <md-card-header><div class="md-title">Purple Cap</div></md-card-header>
      <md-card-content>{{ val.Purple_Cap_Id }}</md-card-content>
    </md-ripple>
   </md-card>
   </div>
  </transition>
  </div>
  </template>
  <script>
  export default {
  data: function() {  return { capData: [], val:'', filter: [], }      }, 
  methods: {  selecteddata (x) { this.val=x; }  },
  mounted () {      
  this.$axios.get('https://mighty-garden-54587.herokuapp.com/getOrangePurpleSeries')
    .then(({ data }) => {
      this.capData = data.data    
     // this.val = data.data[0]     
    })      
  }   
  }
  </script>
```